# Are attorneys, as officers allowed to advocate for positions in supposedly-neutral courtrooms?

Tags: united-states, ohio, advocacy

An Ohio judge [jailed an public defender](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/post-nation/wp/2016/07/25/this-attorney-wore-a-black-live-matter-pin-to-court-and-went-to-jail-for-it/) (and blocked her from appointments for further work) for contempt of court when the attorney refused to remove a "Black Lives Matter" pin.  The logic seems to be (A) courts are supposed to be neutral, (B) neutrality means that officers of the court may not demonstrate non-neutrality, (C) attorneys are officers of the court, and therefore (D) attorneys may not express non-neutral viewpoints.  The judge's specific reasoning, cited at [2:54 in the article video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrO-usgfSKk&feature=youtu.be&t=2m54s), is that "he could not let someone demonstrate a viewpoint in a court that is supposed to be fair and impartial."  That's a very broad rule.

However, that seems to run against the idea that attorneys are supposed to be zealous advocates for their clients' positions in an adversarial system, the opposite of attorney neutrality.

Where does the logic chain in A-B-C-D above break down, or how far does it extend to restrict attorneys' expression of or advocacy for non-neutral positions?

Comment: Presumably one difference is that a political position is not usually related to a client's position at trial. An attorney promoting a (possibly unrelated) political view is arguably detrimental to her client.

Comment: Among other things, the Black Lives Matter movement protests against [at least perceived] over-policing of black neighborhoods, mass incarceration, police brutality, racially-based discrimination in officer discretion around what is treated as a crime/threat/etc. (and/or the similar judicial discretion that applies around sentencing). It would seem very congruent for a public defender to advocate for these things that at least reasonably appear to be in the interests of her clientele, and a little concerning that she's **not allowed** even this small bit of advocacy for those views.

Comment: I agree. But would the members of the jury?

Comment: @WBT The point is that she is supposed to be an active advocate for her client. However, if her client was on the other side, she would be required to just as active for that client. As a result, she must be **personally** neutral in order to fulfill that duty. Consider an author who creates a racist bigoted character that is everything he is personally against or an actor who plays that role. One should not see the personal viewpoint to the detriment of the professional duty.

Comment: @phoog I think that should be up to the members of the jury (if any!) to decide, and it should be up to the atty. to make a prediction about whether or not the reminder would be helpful or hurtful to the point she's trying to make.  If, for example, she's in court on a motion to exclude evidence resulting from police misconduct, it might be helpful.  This conversation is not supposed to be about whether or not she should *wear* the pin, but rather whether or not she should *be allowed to* demonstrate that or any other viewpoint. By this rule, **no** viewpoints may be demonstrated by attorneys.

Comment: @sabbahillel If a young activist, for *any* cause, has enough faith in the system that they think they can do more for the cause by becoming a lawyer and fighting for justice in the courts, as opposed to e.g. protesting in the streets or responding with violence, is that person on becoming a lawyer suddenly supposed to become neutral on even the issue that drove them into the profession?  Should an [Earthjustice](http://earthjustice.org/) attorney be prohibited from wearing a pin or more generally demonstrating a view that "clean water matters?"

Comment: @WBT and when the public defender is up for a case defending a white person who is accused of murdering a black person, should she recuse herself? There would certainly be questions about the propriety of such a button then.

Comment: @phoog Wearing the button during that case would probably not be good advocacy in such a case, but it should still be the advocate's choice based on reasonable predictions of the implications.  Yes, there are some cases that any given attorney should recuse themselves from taking (different cases for different attorneys), but the answer to your question depends a whole lot more on the person's underlying views and conflicts of interest than the actual wearing of any physical pin on any particular day in court.

Comment: @WBT why don't you post an answer then?

Comment: @phoog because the idea in the second paragraph of the question seems to me more true than the first, but the first is an official judge's opinion and seems to be standing law. I'm confused and looking for an answer that draws on more credible sources than I currently am or have.  The linked story mentions the ruling was appealed but I couldn't find any appeals court ruling on that case, just mentions that there are other cases backing up the judge.  How would that ruling likely go?  Why?

Comment: I think that judges are given a fair amount of authority about how cases are conducted, and how people involved in the case comport themselves in the court.  I think the reason for this is that judges are given an enormous responsibility to conduct the proceeding in a fair and efficient way.  Sometimes a judge may seem to be making an arbitrary determination about something that might seem to us to be a bit of a side topic -- but I find it easier to accept these determinations if I think in these terms.